# How can I get the user role name in ASP.NET Update3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently doing an ASP.NET Web Application under MVC in C# using Individual User Accounts. I need to get the Role names for a user. In a previous version the following code would have worked:

```
            foreach (var role in userObject.Roles)
            {
                appUser.RolesForUser.Add(role.Role.Name);
            }
```

but now after doing Update 3, I now get:

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' does not contain a definition for 'Role' and no extension method 'Role' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I would like to know how I can get role names with the new standard. Thanks for any solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Get user roles
var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
```

**Edited**

If you have the userName instead of the userId, you have to retrieve the user using FindByNameAsync instead of FindByIdAsync.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(myName);
```

Once you have the user object, you will be able to get the associated roles just doing:

```
var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
```

Example:

```
//
// GET: /Users/Edit/Bob
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string userName)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

    return View(new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Email = user.Email,
        RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Name
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Could you provide a further example?  In my example I am using a function where I pass the user name and query a ApplicationUser Collection. Although this is different now in update 3. Thanks again.

Comment: @Eddie I've posted an example using user name.

Comment: Thanks @Freerider I am going to have to try your code. Maybe this is going to take some time to catch on!

Comment: @Eddie You can find a useful example installing https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1 NuGet package on a Empty Web Application. This way you check how user roles are retrieved and the how the whole authentication process works too.

Comment: @Freerider Thanks I never thought of nuget actually offering this as well. I would encourage readers to take a step and look at nuget too!

Comment: Anybody reading this post should checkout the nuget link that @Freerider mentioned!

Comment: @Eddie I agree with you that this package is a good tutorial. Thank you for your comments.